# TwitchLib in C# crashes after return values

Tags: c#, return, global-variables, return-value, twitch-api

I wrote my program with many global variables and only with public void methods.
So I want to change my methods to private static methods with return values. That's what I've done.

Now my program will only pass once through "globalChatMessageReceived" of TwitchLib and then it does nothing at all. No problems or errors will display and the program is running correctly and saves data but it will only doing this once.

I am using

```
FindPokemonName(MessageSplitForPokemonName[1]);
```

without return values and

```
(string[] PokedexName, Boolean ChosenPokemonIsAvailable, Boolean ChosenPokemonIsNoStarter, string NameOfChosenPokemon) = FindPokemonName(MessageSplitForPokemonName[1]);
```

with return values.

Here is the code with global variables and no return values:

```
        public void FindTrainerID(string TrainerID, string ChatDisplayName)
        {
            TrainerVorhanden = false;
            if (File.Exists(@"C:\txt\trainer\" + TrainerID + ".txt"))
            {
                string FoundTrainer = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\txt\trainer\" + TrainerID + ".txt");
                Trainer = FoundTrainer.Split('\\');
                TrainerVorhanden = true;
            }

        }
```

And that's what I've done now with return values:

```
        private static (string[] Trainer, bool TrainerAvailable) FindTrainerID(string TrainerID)
        {
            string[] Trainer = new string[5];
            Boolean TrainerAvailable = false;
            if (File.Exists(@"C:\txt\trainer\" + TrainerID + ".txt"))
            {
                string FoundTrainer = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\txt\trainer\" + TrainerID + ".txt");
                Trainer = FoundTrainer.Split('\\');
                TrainerAvailable = true;
            }
            return (Trainer, TrainerAvailable);
        }
```

I tried the program without using the methods with a return value. The program is running constantly with the TwitchLib method "globalChatMessageReceived".

If I'm using return values it does nothing after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it easier to work with a class rather than returning a tuple like this.

For instance, declare this data class:

```cs
class TrainerInfo {
    public string[] Trainer { get; set;}
    public bool TrainerAvailable { get; set;}
}
```

And then give this a try:

```cs
static TrainerInfo FindTrainerID(string TrainerID) {
    var result = new TrainerInfo();

    string trainerPath = $@"D:\junk\trainer\{TrainerID}.txt";
    if (File.Exists(trainerPath)) {
        string FoundTrainer = File.ReadAllText(trainerPath);
        result.Trainer = FoundTrainer.Split('\\').ToArray();
        result.TrainerAvailable = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Also food for thought: Does `Trainer` absolutely *have* to be an array, or could you use a more dynamic collection type (such as `List<string>`)?

Comment: Now I learned how to use `{ get; set;}` , thanks! I didn't understand this until now. But how is this better than using global variables and public void methods? 
Well, if I'm writing a class with 21 public variables, does this have more performance or a better coding than 21 public variables and public void methods in one class? Sorry if I'm asking you, I think I just coded with public void because it was easyer in high school. 
The trainer array always has 6 strings in it, so it doesn't matter imo. But if I am going to code the bag for a trainer it might be better with `List<string>`.

Comment: Localizing variables as much as possible will make your code easier to read, understand and debug in the long run. In some cases making variables unnecessarily global can have an impact on memory because you’re caching data that is not necessarily needed for the entire lifetime of your application.

Comment: Thank you! My only problem is, I can't use the array `Trainer` after executing the method. I thought I would know it but it doesn't work. How do I get the array to use it in another method?

Comment: Well, it might make sense to extract the methods that need access to your array into a class and make it a property of that class. You might want to watch some entry-level videos about object-oriented programming. It’s a little obtuse at first, but once you get the hang of it, it makes *everything* in programming easier. Learning about [S.O.L.I.D principles](https://t.ly/vdr39) in particular really helped me become a better programmer.

Comment: I got it! As I am coding with classes I saw some methods had an instance of my main class for global variables (`PokeTrainerBot Paths = new PokeTrainerBot();`) bc my methods are private and I didn't want to write the paths down many times. With more testing I figured out, that this instance is breaking my program. But I don't need that instance anymore bc I use your coding idea! Many thanks!